# LibGDX Gdxpay requestPurchase not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I've implemented Gdxpay into my libgdx game but when I call requestPurchase(), nothing happens. I followed this tutorial https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay/wiki/Integration-example-with-resolvers but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Here is the main game class where the purchase observer is:

```
public MyGame extends Application adapter {

public MyGame(IActivityRequestHandler handler) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    myRequestHandler = handler;
    // ---- IAP: define products ---------------------
   purchaseManagerConfig = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
   purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(new Offer().setType(OfferType.ENTITLEMENT).setIdentifier(SKU_REMOVE_ADS));
}

public PurchaseObserver purchaseObserver = new PurchaseObserver() {

    @Override
    public void handleRestore (Transaction[] transactions) {
        for (int i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++) {
            if (checkTransaction(transactions[i].getIdentifier()) == true) break;
        }
        // to make a purchase (results are reported to the observer)
        PurchaseSystem.purchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADS);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRestoreError (Throwable e) {
        // getPlatformResolver().showToast("PurchaseObserver: handleRestoreError!");
        Gdx.app.log("ERROR", "PurchaseObserver: handleRestoreError!: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInstall () {
        // getPlatformResolver().showToast("PurchaseObserver: installed successfully...");
        Gdx.app.log("handleInstall: ", "successfully..");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInstallError (Throwable e) {
        //getPlatformResolver().showToast("PurchaseObserver: handleInstallError!");
        Gdx.app.log("ERROR", "PurchaseObserver: handleInstallError!: " + e.getMessage());
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlePurchase (Transaction transaction) {
        checkTransaction(transaction.getIdentifier());
    }

    @Override
    public void handlePurchaseError (Throwable e) {
        if (e.getMessage().equals("There has been a Problem with your Internet connection. Please try again later")) {

            // this check is needed because user-cancel is a handlePurchaseError too)
            // getPlatformResolver().showToast("handlePurchaseError: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        throw new GdxRuntimeException(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlePurchaseCanceled () {
    }
};

protected boolean checkTransaction (String ID) {
    boolean returnbool = false;
    if (SKU_REMOVE_ADS.equals(ID)) {

        myRequestHandler.showAds(false);
        returnbool = true;
    }
    return returnbool;
}

public void create() {
...
```

Here is where requestPurchase is called:

```
public class MainMenu extends Screen {
@Override
public void update() {
...
if (removeBounds.contains(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
MyGame.getPlatformResolver().requestPurchase(MyGame.SKU_REMOVE_ADS);
    }
}
...
}
```

Many thanks.

**Edit: Ok logcat says the following error when I request a purchase:**

```
5188-5220/com.comp.myGame.android I/ERROR﹕ gdx-pay: requestPurchase(): purchaseManager == null
```

**So that means pruchaseManager is null, but according to the tutorial in this instance it should cause the correct purchaseManager to be called so I'm still confused...**

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I followed the tutorial as well, but changed the distributed resolver system to a more local defined system where all app store keys are set in the main game class.

This didn't work (with the same error you got). I then re-engineered the code to follow exactly the tutorial - with all the resolver bells and whistles. Next, I got a "no suitable app store found" error while creating the purchaseManager (at this point, I celebrated because it at least TRIED to create it).

I think that it worked the second try has something to do with the sequence flow:

In the android/AndroidLauncher.java, onCreate:

```
    MyGame myGame = new MyGame(this);
    initialize(myGame, config);

    // init IAP
    myGame.setPlatformResolver(new AndroidResolver(myGame, this));
```

In core/MyGame.java, declarations:

```
    public PurchaseObserver purchaseObserver = new BrainsPurchaseObserver();
    public PurchaseManagerConfig purchaseManagerConfig;
```

In core/MyGame.java, constructor:

```
    purchaseManagerConfig = new PurchaseManagerConfig();
    Offer iap15Tipps = new Offer();
    iap15Tipps.setIdentifier(Product.brains_hints_15.name());
    iap15Tipps.setType(OfferType.CONSUMABLE);
    purchaseManagerConfig.addOffer(iap15Tipps);
```

PlatformResolver.java and AndroidResolver.java as described in the tutorial. This worked to the point of the above error "no app store found".

Then I switched from gdx-pay 0.3.0 to 0.4.0 (by just incrementing the version in the gradle settings, it is already available in the repository), AND IT WORKED!

I suggest you check the sequence of IAP initializing you execute and switch to 0.4.0 if you are not already using it.

-- Michael

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply but I'm afraid it just didn't work for me :( In the end I decided to just scrap the in app purchases for this project.

Comment: how to consume purchased item